# Why is my variable only decrementing once?

Tags: c

This is a game where a robot goes through a whole grid the find markers and return them home. There are 4 markers here. BUT I have an issue with my `findMarkers` variable. It only decrements ONCE, going from 4 to 3.

This results in the robot only deleting the first three markers (i don't even know why), while the `numMarkers` variable stays equal to 3. And so the program keeps running infinitely... The thing is, the program deletes the rectangle from the grid successfully BUT the value stays the same? so I guess the value goes back to being 4 every time?

```
void findMarkers() {

    int iniX = (WindowWidth - (400 / squareSize * squareSize)) / 2;
    int iniY = (WindowHeight - (400 / squareSize * squareSize)) / 2;

    forward();
    sleep(250);
    
    bool foundMarkers = false;
    printf("There are %d markers", numMarkers);
    
    while (foundMarkers == false) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numMarkers; i++) {
            int markerX = markersX[i];
            int markerY = markersY[i];
        
            // Check if the marker is in the current position 
            if (startX == markerX  && startY == markerY) {
                printf("Found a marker at (%d, %d)!\n", startX, startY);
        
                // Remove the collected marker from the list
                for (int j = i; j < numMarkers - 1; j++) {
                    markersX[j] = markersX[j + 1];
                    markersY[j] = markersY[j + 1];
                }
        
                // Remove the collected marker from the grid
                setColour(white);
                fillRect(markerX, markerY, squareSize, squareSize);

                numMarkers=numMarkers-1;
                printf("There are %d left", numMarkers);
                break();
            }
        }
        //Try moving forward
        forward();
        sleep(250);
    
        // If moving forward is not possible

        // The wall to the right is met
        if (startX == iniX + 9 * squareSize) {
            right();
            forward();
            sleep(250);
            right();
            

        // The wall to the left is met
        } else if (startX == iniX) {
            left();
            forward();
            sleep(250);
            left();
        } 
        sleep(250);

        // Check if all markers have been found
        if (numMarkers == 0) {
            foundMarkers = true;
            printf("All markers have been collected!\n");
            returnHome();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; for instance `break` is not a function. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Sara – 
What is seen on your program's standard output?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

When you remove item from an array you should not increment the `i` variable that traverses this array. The variable should have the same value in next iteration to handle the next item. You can fix this if you decrement `i` after the inner `for` loop. Next to the line that decrements `numMarkers` would have the most sense, since both variables control the same loop. This, coupled with the next increment of the outer `for` loop will make it as if `i` didn't change.

In general case, inside the loop with index `i` and total count `n`, you have to decrement this index for every item in the array that is at `i` or before it, but you don't have to do anything for removed items that are after `i`. You must decrement `n` for all removed items.

Comment: I tried decrementing i in the loop as you said : // Remove the collected marker from the grid
                setColour(white);
                fillRect(markerX, markerY, squareSize, squareSize);
                numMarkers=numMarkers-1;
                i=i-1;
                break; But now the numMarkers stays at 4 it does not even decrement once

Comment: @Sara I can't find any errors in the rest of the code. Maybe the error is in the code that is not shown.